# Can't install charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ubuntu

After upgrading Ubuntu 13.04 to 14.04 LTS, the gitlab page display : 502 GitLab is not responding.

I tried, into /home/git/gitlab directory this command : `bundle install` that displays this message :

```
Make sure that `gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

And the result of this command : `gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9.4'` is :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb checking for main() in -licui18n... yes checking for main() in -licui18n... yes checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
        --with-icu-dir
        --without-icu-dir
        --with-icu-include
        --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
        --with-icu-lib
        --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/lib
        --with-icui18nlib
        --without-icui18nlib
        --with-icui18nlib
        --without-icui18nlib extconf.rb:55:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/src (Errno::ENOENT)
        from extconf.rb:55:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4 for inspection. Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/gem_make.out
```

Of course, directory `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/` contains only 3 files : extconf.rb, gem_make.out, mkmf.log

But, this directory `/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/src` contains 2 files : file-soft-check.patch, file-5.08.tar.gz and 1 directory : file-5.08/

I tired a symlink, but is remove every time I run the command.

Can someone help me ?

Thank you

---

Thank you for your reply. A new error when running this command:

> bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb --with-dldflags=-licuuc -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
  -- tar zxvf file-5.08.tar.gz
  -- ./configure --prefix=/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/ --disable-shared --enable-static --with-pic
  -- patch -p0 < ../file-soft-check.patch
  -- make -C src install
  -- make -C magic install
checking for main() in -lmagic_ext... yes
checking for magic.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling encoding_detector.c
In file included from encoding_detector.c:3:0:
common.h:14:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_enc_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char *str, size_t len, void *encoding)
              ^
compiling ext.c
In file included from ext.c:1:0:
common.h:14:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_enc_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char *str, size_t len, void *encoding)
              ^
common.h:23:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str(const char *str, size_t len)
              ^
common.h:32:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char *str)
              ^
compiling converter.c
In file included from converter.c:2:0:
common.h:23:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str(const char *str, size_t len)
              ^
common.h:32:14: warning: ‘charlock_new_str2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char *str)
              ^
compiling transliterator.cpp
In file included from transliterator.cpp:1:0:
common.h:14:14: warning: ‘VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char*, size_t, void*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_enc_str(const char *str, size_t len, void *encoding)
              ^
common.h:32:14: warning: ‘VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static VALUE charlock_new_str2(const char *str)
              ^
linking shared-object charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.a(smpdtfmt.ao): réadressage R_X86_64_PC32 vers symbole « _ZN6icu_5216SimpleDateFormat22fgCalendarFieldToLevelE » ne peut pas être utilisé en créant un objet partagé ; recompilé avec -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: édition de lien finale en échec: Mauvaise valeur
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [charlock_holmes.so] Erreur 1
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a problem related to the new libicu version (icu-52 instead of the old icu-51)
This worked for me:

Remove charlock_holmes:

```
bundle exec gem uninstall charlock_holmes
```

then re-execute Bundle install 
(Postgres):

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test mysql aws
```

(Or MySQL):

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

Comment: The proposed review was incorrect 
For Postgres note, the option says "without ... mysql"

see: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#install-gems

Answer (score 2):

Try installing icu4 from source

```
cd /tmp
wget http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/52.1/icu4c-52_1-src.tgz
tar zxf icu4c-52_1-src.tgz
cd icu/source
sudo ./configure --prefix /opt/icu4c-52 && sudo make && sudo make install
```

And then try install charlock_holmes with the icu4 path

```
gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icu-dir=/opt/icu4c-52/
```

Comment: Thank you, it resolved my issue. I used higher version https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-68-2/icu4c-68_2-src.tgz

Answer (score 2):

I really like @vikingo710 answer. It got me 90% of the way. Even though their solution worked to install, RubyGems could not find the files when calling the gem (for me it was called when I ran `bundle exec puma`) Here is my write up to fix my particular issue:

### The problem

A new machine will install icu4c 59.1 or greater as a dependency, this is a result of a failing bundle install that will prompt you to run `brew install icu4c`. Icu4c 59.1 is incompatible with charlock_holmes version 0.6.9.4 due to the way that C++11 files are read and complied.

### Solution

Solution is to install an older version of icu4c. Homebrew doesn’t allow you to do this easily so we will install icu4c 58.2 from it’s source, then move it into a homebrew folder and tell homebrew to symlink it so that RubyGems can find it when it is being called by charlock_holmes.

### Dependencies

`brew install wget`

### Building from source

- `cd /tmp`
- `wget http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/58.2/icu4c-58_2-src.tgz`
- `tar zxf icu4c-58_2-src.tgz`
- `cd icu/source`
- `sudo ./configure --prefix /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c-58/58.2 && sudo make && sudo make install`
- That last command will build icu4c into a homebrew folder. If this doesn’t work because of permissions then build elsewhere like /usr/local/opt/icu4c-58/58.2 and move it into that folder after.

### PATH

- You will need to add reference to this source in your bash profile (might not  be needed if it successfully symlinked)
- In your .bash_profile add

  - `PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c-58/bin:$PATH"`
  - `PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c-58/sbin:$PATH"`
  - Change the path if you installed it elsewhere.

### Linking

You might need to make sure that other versions of icu4c are not installed. If this is the case:

- `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies icu4c`
- `brew link icu4c-58`

### Installing

- Make sure the gem is uninstalled
- `gem uninstall charlock_holmes`

This should be enough. From the BE repo you should be able to successfully run:

- `bundle install`
- `bundle exec puma`

If you get errors you might need to uninstall charlock_holmes again and run

- `bundle config build.charlock_holmes --with-icu-dir=/usr/local/opt/icu4c-58/`
- `bundle install`

This means that you would have icu4c-58 both in ^ and in /usr/local/Cellar/

Comment: Thank you, it resolved my issue. I used higher version https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-68-2/icu4c-68_2-src.tgz